# Is there a way to use Subdivision Surface Modifier with text model without deformations of model?

Tags: text-object, subdivision-surface

Is there a way to use Subdivision Surface Modifier with text model without deformations of model? CRTL+R and adding new edge to model does not work. As you can see on image C, S, Z letters are deformate.[image: example]

Comment: Change to simple instead of Catmull-Clark

Comment: Most likely adding loopcut doesn't do anything because after converting topology of the letters consists of all tris which Loopcut will skip for cutting. So if you want text letter suitable for subsurfing change its topology which is called retopology. Easiest way would be to add Remesh modifier above Subsurf (note - this is a lazy way)

Comment: Text objects have really horrible topology.  Subsurf requires good topology to look good.  You will have to retopologize the text, either with a remesh modifier or manually.

Comment: Change to simple still cause deformations but less and with bad visibility effect. How I should use remesh modifier?

Comment: @user40098 [Here's how to use the Remesh Modifier on text.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33494/morphing-between-two-different-curves-or-meshes-via-shapekeys/46106#46106)